# JPA Hibernate How to call user db function in select

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-annotations

I have a legacy application I am converting to JPA. One of the SELECT queries, I am trying to replicate has a field that is a database user created function.
eg.: SELECT DBFIELD1, DBFIELD2, DBFIELD3, USER_FUNCTION(DBFIELD1) FROM .... WHERE ....

The USER_FUNCTION has quite a bit of business functionality and I cannot replicate it and retain the performance parameters required. It has to be retained.

I have replicated the predicates and the database fields. How do I define this column in my Entity. Is there a way to closely mimic the same SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Solved...
Create the entity as follows.

```
@Formula("USER_FUNCTION(DBFIELD1)")
private float userFunctionResult;

public float getUserFunctionResult() {
    return userFunctionResult;
}
```